# Ordering query results on expressions referencing properties of other entities

Tags: guidewire, gosu

In the *Ordering results* subsection of the *Query builder APIs* part of the Gosu reference guide, there is a listing showing how to order the result set of a simple query, based on (database-backed) properties of other entities. For example, to sort CC notes based on the property `Activity#LastViewedDate`, we can simply write

```
uses gw.api.database.Query 
uses gw.api.database.QuerySelectColumns
uses gw.api.path.Paths

var queryNotes = Query.make(Note)  // Query for notes
var resultNotes = queryNotes.select()

// Sort the notes by related date on activity
resultNotes.orderBy(QuerySelectColumns.path(Paths.make(Note#Activity, Activity#LastViewedDate)))
```

Is there any way to order the result set of a query based on calculated properties in a situation when it's necessary to join the related entity to the main query? For example, given the code shown below, is it possible for the DATEDIFF clause to reference the property `Claim#LossDate`?

```
function loadExposures(asOfDate : Date, policyNumber : String) : IQueryBeanResult<Exposure> {
    var queryExposure = Query.make(Exposure)
    var claimTable = queryExposure.join(Exposure#Claim)
    var policyTable = claimTable.join(Claim#Policy)

    policyTable.compare(Policy#PolicyNumber, Relop.Equals, policyNumber)

    var selectExposure = queryExposure.select()
    selectExposure.orderBy(QuerySelectColumns.dbFunction(DBFunction.Expr({"DATEDIFF(''days'', ", queryExposure.getColumnRef("Claim.LossDate"), ", ''${asOfDate}'')"})))
    selectExposure.thenBy(QuerySelectColumns.path(Paths.make(Exposure#Claim, Claim#ClaimNumber)))
    selectExposure.thenBy(QuerySelectColumns.path(Paths.make(Exposure#ClaimOrder)))

    return selectExposure
}
```

Obviously, `queryExposure.getColumnRef("Claim.LossDate")` doesn't work because the `LossDate` column can only be accessed through the reference `claimTable`. However, writing `claimTable.getColumnRef("LossDate")` won't work either because the root type of the `claimTable` object is `entity.Claim`. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I ask what the specific problem you are trying to address is? Here is my assumption:

From the function name and arguments it appears like you are trying to load all exposures related to a certain PolicyNumber and then orderBy (ascending implied) the result of the DATEDIFF function comparing the Claim LossDate to your passed in argument. All LossDate's before the passed in value will have a positive value from the DATEDIFF function and all LossDate's after the passed in value will have a negative value. So this ordering is essentially the same as simply ordering the exposures by Claim LossDate (descending). I think you can achieve what you want to do by:

`selectExposure.orderByDescending(QuerySelectColumns.path(Paths.make(Exposure#Claim, Claim#LossDate)))`

In this case you wouldn't even need to pass in an 'asOfDate' argument, unless you wanted to use this filter out some records based on that date.

Comment: Sorry, the first rows returned by the example query should be those with `LossDate` closest to the reference date, that is, the first ordering call should be `selectExposure.orderBy(QuerySelectColumns.dbFunction(DBFunction.Expr({"ABS(DATEDIFF(''days'', ", queryExposure.getColumnRef("Claim.LossDate"), ", ''${asOfDate}''))"})))`.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense. I think you will have to make the absolute value DB function a column (with alias) that you select and then sort the results by that alias. Something like in the link below (Guidewire login required), except that you also want to sort on the DB function column after calling select()
https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1020/integration/topics/querybuilderapi/c_agg-func-col-selection.html

Comment: How bad would it be if I converted the result set of the query to a normal list and then sorted it using a comparator?

Comment: It would be slower than doing the sorting in the DB for sure. But if there is no way to sort in the DB, I might resort to converting to a list and sorting in the application code. However, you should determine what is the maximum number of Exposures that could be fetched for a single policy number is before putting this into production, just to be sure you wouldn't be pulling thousands of Exposures from the DB for certain PolicyNumbers. If you are displaying the results in an LV, converting to a list also makes the pull as you go paging on the PCF not work.

Comment: I just hoped there still might be a way to implement this that would not require me to use row queries, but if it's not possible, it's fine. If there is no other answer, in a few days I will mark yours as accepted. Thank you for your time.